# How to group by in Motor 1.1?

Tags: python, mongodb, tornado-motor

I'm using Motor async client for mongoDB in current project, and I'd like to use aggregation like group by for query. Docs contain short info about group, but no examples how.

Parameters:

1. key: fields to group by (see above description)
2. condition: specification of rows to be considered (as a find() query
   specification)
3. initial: initial value of the aggregation counter object
4. reduce: aggregation function as a JavaScript string

I don't know what exactly means initial parameter and reduce (as a javascript string?).
Can you prodive an example?

Comment: I've figured out, that Motor can use aggregate method, in which we can apply pipelines, that use native mongodb query lang. But I'd like to know about method group().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Motor's `group` method takes the same parameters as PyMongo's. Adapting the [PyMongo group example](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/aggregation.html#group) to Motor:

```
from bson.code import Code
from tornado import ioloop, gen
from motor import MotorClient

reducer = Code("""
               function(obj, prev){
                 prev.count++;
               }
               """)

db = MotorClient().test


@gen.coroutine
def example():
    yield db.things.remove({})
    yield db.things.insert_many([
        {'x': 1},
        {'x': 2},
        {'x': 2},
        {'x': 3},
    ])

    results = yield db.things.group(key={"x": 1}, condition={},
                                    initial={"count": 0}, reduce=reducer)
    for doc in results:
        print(doc)


ioloop.IOLoop.current().run_sync(example)
```

This prints:

```
{'count': 1.0, 'x': 1.0}
{'count': 2.0, 'x': 2.0}
{'count': 1.0, 'x': 3.0}
```

Comment: However, aggregation is faster, works sharded, and uses indexes. I recommend the aggregation framework over "group".

Comment: So it really need js code in reducer? As for aggregation: it contains fewer code, and seems to be simpler => only nosql for mongo